# Does the word “unwaivable” block me from canceling a contract?

Tags: contract-law

The first sentence in contract reads. “you have an unwaivable right to cancel this contract for any reason within 10 days after the date you signed this contract”. Can I cancel? Or does the word(UNWAIVABLE) cause a problem?

Comment: FWIW, this right to cancel the contract that can't be waived is probably just restating a statutory right.

Answer (score 6):

The contract could be rewritten thus:

> you have the right to cancel this contract for any reason within 10 days after the date you signed this contract.  This right cannot be waived.

Because the right cannot be waived, you will always have that right within the 10-day period unless there is some statutory provision that overrides this contract term.  (Most such overriding statutes favor the consumer, however, so this is unlikely.)

You ask "Can I cancel?"  If it is now within 10 days of the date you signed the contract, you can certainly cancel under this term of the contract.  If it is now beyond ten days from the date you signed the contract then you might be able to cancel based on some other term of the contract or based on some statutory provision that isn't mentioned in the contract.  We haven't seen the whole contract, and we don't know where you are, so we can't say what might be possible after the ten days have elapsed.

Comment: A cynical observer might conclude that the wording of the contract was deliberately more difficult to read than it could have been in order to confuse people and discourage them from exercising the right to cancel.

Comment: @ohwilleke, Or a cynical observer might conclude that some rookie lawyer thought it sounded somehow more "thorough" to add this verbiage...  (*because what reason might anybody have to ever consider waiving their right to terminate an agreement?*)

Answer (score 3):

No, it doesn't block you.

In fact it actually has the opposite effect - it *guarantees* that you may cancel the contract.

Consider an alternate wording *without* that term:

> You have a right to cancel this contract for any reason within 10 days after the date you signed this contract.

If you had waived your right to cancel, but later changed your mind and decided you wanted to cancel, they could prevent you by claiming that you waived your right to do so.

However, since this right is *unwaivable*, there is nothing whatsoever preventing you from cancelling.